# I should be getting an output with html information, but I get nothing instead

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, web-scraping

I'm learning how to webscrape through online videos and this is the code they gave me:

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanye_West")

type(res)

res.text
```

They're doing it with Jupyter notebook while I'm using VSCode. My output when I run this is nothing, but when they run it they get a bunch of stuff from the html

[image: what I get]

What they get:

```
'<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n    <meta charset="utf-8" />\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />\n    <style type="text/css">\n    body {\n        background-color: #f0f0f2;\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n        \n    }\n    div {\n        width: 600px;\n        margin: 5em auto;\n        padding: 2em;\n        background-color: #fdfdff;\n        border-radius: 0.5em;\n        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);\n    }\n    a:link, a:visited {\n        color: #38488f;\n        text-decoration: none;\n    }\n    @media (max-width: 700px) {\n        div {\n            margin: 0 auto;\n            width: auto;\n        }\n    }\n    </style>    \n</head>\n\n<body>\n<div>\n    <h1>Example Domain</h1>\n    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>\n    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

Comment: `print(res.text)`.

Comment: in scripts you have to use `print()` to display something - so you can decide what you want to see. And Juputer was created to run code partially and test code - and to make life easier it automatically displays result from last command in cell.